# What DNS resolver does safari use?

Tags: macos, safari, vpn, web-browser, web-browsing

After reading this article about Firefox and VPNs, the section titled “Avoid untrustworthy resolvers by using Trusted Recursive Resolver” talks about using Cloudflare’s recursive resolver.

I’m trying to find out what resolver Safari uses?

Article:

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/05/a-cartoon-intro-to-dns-over-https/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safari uses the macOS systemwide DNS resolvers.

You can print the current resolvers configuration using **`scutil --dns`**.